# Is this always true: $P(A|B) = 1-P(A^c|B)$?

Tags: probability

Does this identity hold for all events?

$$
P(A|B) = 1-P(A'|B)
$$

Logically speaking, if the probability of $A$ given $B$ occurred is $X$, shouldn't the probability that $A$ does not occur, $A'$, given $B$, be similarly $1-X$?

There is a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436718/conditional-probability-with-bayes-rule).

This is the closest that I could get to proving (or disproving) it:

1. $P(A\cap B)=P(A)-P(A' \cap B)$
2. $P(A|B)P(B)=P(A)-P(A'|B)P(B)$
3. $\therefore P(A'|B)= \frac {P(A)} {P(B)}-P(A|B)$

Are there are certain formulae which can be used to prove this? Or does the identity only hold under certain situations, and if so, what kind of situations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Does this identity hold for all events?
>
> $P(A\mid B)=1−P(A^\prime\mid B)$
>
> Logically speaking, if the probability of A given B occurred is X, shouldn't the probability that A does not occur, A′, given B, be similarly 1−X?

Yes.  The complement rule holds for conditional probabilities.

$$\begin{align}\Pr(B) & = \Pr((A\cap B) \cup (A^\prime\cap B)) & \text{by total probability law} \\ & = \Pr(A\cap B)+\Pr(A^\prime\cap B) & \text{because of mutual exclusion} \\ \implies \Pr(A\cap B) & = \Pr(B)-\Pr(A^\prime\cap B) & \text{by rearangement}\\\therefore \Pr(A\mid B)&=1 - \Pr(A^\prime\mid B) & \text{by division by }\Pr(B)\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for affirming it, but is there a proof of this relation?

Comment: @PlasticAstronaut Yes, just completed the edit.

Comment: @GrahamKemp: there may be a typo on the third line: $ \Rightarrow P(A \cap B)$

Comment: @Alex Oh, yes, indeed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The above answer is correct, just for clarification your step 1. in the proof in the question is incorrect.

1. $P(A\cap B) = P(A) - P(A\cap B')$

or

1. $P(A\cap B) = P(B) - P(A'\cap B)$

would be true.