# What is the name for this probablity law: $P(A\mid B)=1-P(A'\mid B)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

What is the name for this probability law:
$$P(A\mid B)=1-P(A'\mid B).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It is called the Complement Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825698/is-this-always-true-pab-1-pacb?noredirect=1&lq=1).

(taken from comment by [Decaf-Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/227902/decaf-math))